# Корректная реализация шаблона проектирования "Состояние" aka "State"

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Подскажите, где я ошибаюсь. Есть задача - написать программу-симулятор включения и выключения ПК. Симуляция этих операций будет приближена к реальности, но не доподлинно. В комментариях подсказали использовать шаблон поведения"Состояние".
Вот, что у меня получилось.
Структура проекта

[image: структура проекта]

Реализация **Computer**

```
internal class Computer
    {
        public IPCState State { get; set; }

        public Computer() { }

        public Computer(IPCState state) => State = state;

        public bool TurnOn() => State.TurnON(this);

        public bool TurnOff() => State.TurnOff(this);
    }
```

Интерфейс **IPCState**

```
    internal interface IPCState
    {
        bool TurnON(Computer computer);

        bool TurnOff(Computer computer);
    }
```

Пример реализации одно из классов-загрузчиков

```
internal class LoaderOfTheSecondLevel : IPCState
    {
        // Передача управления исполняемому коду, записанному в PBS (Partition Boot Sector - загрузочный сектор активного раздела)
        internal bool IsPBSActive { get; private set; }

        public LoaderOfTheSecondLevel() { }

        public LoaderOfTheSecondLevel(bool state) => IsPBSActive = state;

        public bool TurnOff(Computer computer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool TurnON(Computer computer)
        {
            if (IsPBSActive)
            {
                computer.State = new LoaderOfTheThirdLevel();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Уверен, что делаю что-то не так, потому что как видно из кода выше, я делаю зачем-то **computer.State = new LoaderOfTheThirdLevel();**, но потом нигде не использую. Делаю потому, что в примере на метаните было что-то похожее.

Ну и **Main**

```
List<bool> operationRes = new List<bool>();

            PowerSocket.SetElectricityState(true);
            Computer computer = new Computer(new SystemStartup());
            operationRes.Add(computer.TurnOn());
            computer = new Computer(new LoaderOfTheFirstLevel());
            operationRes.Add(computer.TurnOn());
            computer = new Computer(new LoaderOfTheSecondLevel(operationRes.Last()));
            operationRes.Add(computer.TurnOn());
            computer = new Computer(new LoaderOfTheThirdLevel(operationRes.Last()));
            operationRes.Add(computer.TurnOn());
            computer = new Computer(new BootLoaderOSKernel(operationRes.Last()));
            operationRes.Add(computer.TurnOn());

            if (operationRes.All(r => r))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OS is ready to work");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Расскажите, что делаю не так.

Comment: Как только вы сказали "включение" и "выключение" вы должны были сказать слово "состояние" и подумать о паттерне состояние и стейт машинах. Язык программирования не указан, пусть будут плюсы и шарп: http://rsdn.org/article/alg/Static_Finite_State_Machine.xml и https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.6.php

Comment: @AK, сначала я примерно понял как его реализовать, а потом вспомнил о том, что моя модель вкл будет делать следующее(очень обобщенно): есть несколько этапов загрузки пк, на каждом из этапов участвуют отдельные компоненты, которые в случае успешного завершения своих процессов будет передавать управление на следующие этапы следующим компонентам. Можете немного объяснить, как бы в реализовывали такую модель, используя шаблон "состояние"?

Comment: И? Чистой воды стейт машина. "Есть несколько этапов загрузки ПК" -- рисуете граф состояний, прописываете откуда какие переходы нужны, потом какие действия выполнять. Возможно, вы не понимаете устройство стейт-машин? Меня вот это смущает: "отдельные компоненты, которые в случае успешного завершения своих процессов будет передавать управление на следующие этапы следующим компонентам". Вы почему-то мыслите дело так, будто стейт машина запускает компонент и потом компонент управляет запуском других компонентов. Нет же! Переходом по состояниям управляет сама машина, она сама запускает компоненты.

Comment: @AK позвольте еще вопрос. Вроде я его реализовал, но меня смущает такой момент: в конечном итоге я буду запускать каждый из компонентов от лица машины? То есть, запустил первый компонент загрузки, если он вернул true, от машины запускаю второй компонент и т.д?

Comment: Судя по всему вы решили на c# писать. И на вопросе нет метки языка c#, так что почти никто из участников его не смотрел, а вы [гадаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1148825/) почему. Ну-ну. Кстати, статья именно по шарпу в помощь: https://habr.com/post/160105/

Comment: @AK спасибо за редактирование метки, читал статью еще вчера. Честно говоря, не получает корректно это реализовать.

Comment: Показали как это правильно будет для моего случая вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721551/correct-state-pattern-implementation/62744840#62744840)