# Правильное использование Async/Await при работе с БД через Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, асинхронность

Назрел следующий вопрос.

Есть задача - все запросы к БД должны происходить в асинхронном режиме.
Я примерно представляю(и реализовал) такую возможность, но мне кажется, что я где-то сделал ошибку.

Инициатором самого обращения к БД служит обработка события нажатия на кнопку

```
private async void MenuItem_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ShowFrameInBrowser((await _videos.GetAsync((int)VideoNames.RAMWork)).URL);
                ActionsToMakeVisibleBrowser();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

далее мы приходим вот сюда

```
public async Task<Video> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            using (_db = new VideosContext(_options))
            {
                if (_db.Videos.AsNoTracking().Any(v => v.Id == id))
                {
                    return await _db.Videos.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync(v => v.Id == id);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("По указанному индексу не нашлось видео");
                }
            }
        }
```

Работает-то оно все как надо(по моим меркам), но что я не до конца понимаю - в каком месте должен стоять **await** в 2-х случаях:

1. Когда метод возвращает **void**
2. Когда метод возвращает **Task**

Насколько я понимаю, после того как написано **await** весь код ниже будет выполняться и так в другом потоке.

И у меня 2 вопроса:

1. Первое обращение к БД в методе выше происходит в этой строчке
   `_db.Videos.AsNoTracking().Any(v => v.Id == id)` и я хотел
   именно здесь применить конструкцию await, но, поскольку я должен
   вернуть **Task**, я этого не делаю. Правильно ли я поступаю?
2. Если метод возвращает void, то я должен ставить await при первом обращении к БД как в примере ниже?

```
        public async void CreateAsync(Video item)
        {
            using (_db = new VideosContext(_options))
            {
                if(!await _db.Videos.AnyAsync(v => v.Name == item.Name))
                {
                    _db.Add(item);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Попытка добавить существующее видео")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110213/discussion-on-question-by-the-konstantin---async-await-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря советам от aepot, VladD и Grundy получилось то, что я хотел сделать. Спасибо.

Что изменилось в коде.

Если вы не хотите,

> чтобы вас закидали гнилыми помидорами

избегайте использования *async void*. Потому что асинхронные методы этого типа нельзя ожидать и, как в моем примере, выбрасывать исключение. Поэтому вид метода, где возвращаемым результатом является void, можно изменить на следующий:

```
public async Task<bool> TryCreateAsync(Video item)
{
    using (_db = new VideosContext(_options))
    {
        if(!_db.Videos.Any(v => v.Name == item.Name))
        {
            _db.Add(item);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Также я понял, что `await` не создает отдельный поток для выполнения, а

> ключевое слово await делает две вещи: указывает точку возможного
> прерывания/возобновления метода; возможного -- потому что если таск
> уже завершен, то метод продолжит выполнение и прерываться не будет
> извлекает результат или исключение из таска, который возвращается
> ожидаемым методом Т.е. никакого отношения к потокам эти два слова не
> имеют
> как указано в одном из ответов [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-async-await-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD/491783#491783) вопроса.

Comment: _никогда не используйте конструкцию Async/Await, если возвращаемый результат метода void ._ Можно просто заменить на _избегайте использования `async void`_. На английском SO так и пишут _avoid `async void`_.

Comment: @aepot помимо вашего предложения по оптимизации этого кода(в коментах есть ссылка), стоит ли еще добавить await в такие места, где это возможно? К примеру, вместо _db.Add(item); сделать await _db.AddAsync(item);?

Comment: Если API `VideosContext` имеет данный метод, и метод требует I/O операции, то да, было бы полезно вызывать асинхронно.

Comment: Я имею в виду, присутствует ли данный метод в классе `VideosContext`. Хочу только предупредить, что если сама операция выполняется быстро, скажем, быстрее 30мс, то накладные расходы на `async` машину состояний и переключение контекстов могут потребить больше времени и ресурсов компьютера, чем обычный синхронный вызов. Все хорошо в меру.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, учту.

Comment: А так то в общем случае да, если у вас асинхронный метод, то надо стараться в нём использовать асинхронные версии вызываемых вами функций.